# Compare two strings - get right part of the longer one

Tags: c

I have two strings, e.g.:

- `str1 = "aaabbbcccdddeee"`
- `str2 = "aaabbbccc"`

How to do something like `str1 - str2` to get the `dddeee` substring?

Comment: Is `str2` guaranteed to be the prefix of `str1`?

Comment: What happens if `str1` doesn't begin with `str2`? e.g. str1 = "aaabbbxxxdddeee" and str2 = "aaabbbccc"? What do you want the output to be in this case?

Comment: thanks, str2 is prefix of str1..

Comment: If you want to find the longest common substring then check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem for som ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `str2` is guaranteed to be a prefix of `str1`, then this will suffice:

```
const char *str3 = &str1[strlen(str2)];
```

which is equivalent to this: (as @James points out in the comments)

```
const char *str3 = str1 + strlen(str2);
```

Of course, `str3` is just a pointer into one of the original strings.  If the contents of the original string changes, then so will your result.  So you may want to create a copy, using `malloc()` and `strcpy()` (and then `free()` at some point).

Answer (score 2):

This will skip the common prefix of two strings:

```
char* suffix(const char* prefix, const char* str) {
    while (*prefix && *str && *prefix == *str) {
        prefix++;
        str++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

For example, if you pass `"AAB"` and `"AACC"`, this would return `"CC"`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have clarified that `str2` is a prefix of `str1`, you can get the pointer to the extra part in `str2` simply with the operation:

```
str1 + strlen(2);
```

For example, to print the "dddeee" part of your string:

```
printf("%s\n", str1 + strlen(str2));
```

How this works is simple. `str1 + strlen(str2)` is a pointer that is `strlen(str2)` N characters away from the beginning of the string pointed to be `str1`. `strlen(str2)` returns the number of characters in the second string and you skip those many characters in the first string and reach the extra part.

Answer (score 1):

str3 will contain a *copy* of the prefix:

```
str1 = "aaabbbcccdddeee"
str2 = "aaabbbccc"

size_t length = strlen1 - strlen2; 
char* str3 = calloc(sizeof(char), length + 1);

memcpy(str3, str1+strlen(str2), length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "aaaabbbbbdddeee";
    char b[] = "aaaabbbbb";

    const char* start = strstr(a, b);
    if (start)
    {
        printf("%s\n", a + strlen(b));
    }

    return 0;
}
```